# How do I schedule a post on Threads?

Tags: web-apps, threads

Threads doesn't natively support scheduling posts.

I'm trying to help a social media manager.

Is there a tool that will allow me to schedule posts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to this Reddit post, this is available for some marketing services.

- HootSuite (https://blog.hootsuite.com/how-to-schedule-threads-posts-instagram/)
- SproutSocial
- Social News Desk ([https://www.socialnewsdesk.com/threads-beta-now-available-to-all-social-news-desk-customers/?utm\_medium=social&utm\_source=threads\_](https://www.socialnewsdesk.com/threads-beta-now-available-to-all-social-news-desk-customers/?utm%5C_medium=social&utm%5C_source=threads%5C_))
- Sprinklr (https://www.sprinklr.com/blog/sprinklr-enables-threads/)

**Source**

- https://techcrunch.com/2024/03/01/threads-says-it-will-make-its-api-broadly-available-by-june/?guccounter=1
- https://www.reddit.com/r/ThreadsApp/comments/1b45gt4/schedule_posts_on_threads_is_now_available/